# Multiplayer movement interpolation - prediction

Tags: network-programming, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I written script for interpolation and movement but it's not working good enough, especially prediction which just uses object velocity multiplied by delay time (syncVelocity * syncDelay) causing player to return to the position before prediction when he stops moving. I've heard it can be improved using unity navmesh class but I have no idea how to do it. Any idea how to improve that script?

Link to the docs: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/NavMesh.html

```
public class Synchronization : MonoBehaviour {

    private float lastSynchronizationTime = 0f;
    private float syncDelay = 0f;
    private float syncTime = 0f;

    private Vector3 syncStartPosition = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 syncEndPosition = Vector3.zero;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (!networkView.isMine){

            SyncedMovement();

        }
    }

    void OnSerializeNetworkView(BitStream stream, NetworkMessageInfo info)
    {

        Vector3 syncPosition = Vector3.zero;
        Vector3 syncVelocity = Vector3.zero;

        if (stream.isWriting)
        {
            syncPosition = transform.position;
            stream.Serialize(ref syncPosition);

            syncVelocity = GetComponent<CharacterController>().velocity;
            stream.Serialize(ref syncVelocity);
        }
        else
        {
            stream.Serialize(ref syncPosition);

            stream.Serialize(ref syncVelocity);

            syncTime = 0f;
            syncDelay = Time.time - lastSynchronizationTime;
            lastSynchronizationTime = Time.time;

            syncStartPosition = transform.position;
            syncEndPosition = syncPosition + syncVelocity * syncDelay;
        }
    }

    void SyncedMovement(){

        syncTime += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(syncStartPosition, syncEndPosition, syncTime / syncDelay);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're calling "prediction" is actually called [extrapolation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking#Entity_interpolation).  "Prediction" is [something else entirely](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking#Input_prediction).

Comment: Did you come out with any solution?